# Implement Association in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, bigdata, database, nosql

I need to implement association between objects in MongoDB to allow retrieval queries from any level. Suppose I have a model **Account->Application->Device->users**. suppose I want to query on user collection using account reference, or say from any level of hierarchy I want to query on users.

As we have no support for joins I cannot keep a separate association collection, even if I keep a association collection I will have to do series of queries, and the output from association collection can be a huge array of objects and I will be left with two options to use

1. iterative query for each object from array
2. use $in operator

both are disastrous to use if the array is big.

I have figured out an approach to keep a tree of ancestors like as follow document.

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(""),
    Name:"",
    Timestamp:ISODate(" "),
    ...
    ancestors :[{_id:ObjectId(""),..},{_id:ObjectId(""),..},{_id:ObjectId(""),..}]
}
```

Suppose this is users document with ancestors as deviceId,applicationId,accountId.
I am not sure how useful it will be.
One thing I am sure about the above model is that if any new level in added updating is going to be an pain.

The main thing why I want to implement this model is to implement a loosely coupled model.

Thanks is Advance!!!

Comment: What exactly is the question or problem? Good schema design answers require good explanation of the use case with example queries. As it stands this question is too vague to helpfully answer since it seems to ask "how should I do every possible query on this ill-specified bunch of related things?". Perhaps check out [data modeling docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/) to get started on how to think about data modeling?

Comment: @wdberkeley ok, we have a collection raw_data which contains data from device,we has hierarchy as Account->department->application->raw_data,we provide real-time analytics on the raw data on dashboard and this was related to mobile application, for each analysis query basically aggregation queries i had maintained AppltnId in each document of raw_data collection and all queries need to have AppltnId in $match pipeline.Now we are planing to go from mobile industry to other industries and the structure might be different and even want to provide API and not restrict only to portal analytics.

Comment: And want to query from any level using AccountId say for instance or deparmentId. And for other industries the hierarchy may not be the same, and we want to maintain raw data in raw_data collection, and provide analysis on raw_data, so i want to restructure the raw_data document and the above mentioned schema is what am thinking of implementing

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand - editing the question with example documents/queries is the way to go here. I kind of understand the deal with the hierarchy, but then you say it might not be the same? Also, where do departments/departmenid come into this? The question needs to focus on something precise to ask about a precise structure or set of queries/questions to answer.